# Dynamically trim stdout line width in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, cut

Lately, I have been experimenting with the `ps` command, and sometimes long paths wrap to the next line (or two) and make it hard to read. I want to pipe the `ps` output into another program to limit the output to `x` number of characters.

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work quite right:

```
ps aux | cut -c1-$(stty size | cut -d' ' -f2)
```

`$(stty size | cut -d' ' -f2)` evaluates to 167, but doesn't seem to be valid input for `cut`.

Is there a way to get this type of syntax to work in bash?

Comment: This work for me. Can you provide some output?

Comment: where is the dynamic part? You want a different length for certain conditions? It seems like you want to limit all output to one maximum length

Comment: @awk_FTW Depending on the situation, I have different window settings. At fullscreen, my width is 167. But at other sizes, I will need to be smaller. That's why I want to call ssty to get the size.

Comment: Try `tput rmam; ps aux`

Comment: Some shells like `zsh`, `ksh93` or `bash` store the terminal width in `$COLUMNS`

Comment: All the answers here fail when the output being trimmed (eg some command other than ps) contains ANSI color characters. They trim the line after too few characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following works:

```
ps aux | cut -c1-$(stty size </dev/tty | cut -d' ' -f2)
```

This also works:

```
v=$(stty size | cut -d' ' -f2) ; ps aux | cut -c1-$v
```

The problem seems to be that `stty` needs to have the tty on its standard input in order to function.  The above two approaches solve that.

There is still another option.  While `stty`'s stdin and stdout are both redirected in the above commands, its stderr is not: it still points to a terminal.  Strangely enough, `stty` will also work if it is given stderr as its input:

```
ps aux | cut -c1-$(stty size <&2 | cut -d' ' -f2)
```

Comment: Indeed, it does! This was exactly what I was looking for. Just curious, why did you add the tee tt at the end?

Comment: @lentils Oops, the `tee` was added when I was debugging.  It is gone now.

Comment: What does <&2 refer to? I have never seen that notation before.

Comment: @lentils In the shell, files are numbered.  Zero refers to standard input, one to standard output, and two to standard error.  The expression `<&2` means get your input from standard error.

Comment: Very cool. I know < is the input operator, but what about &? Does it have any uses beyond stdin, stdout, and stderr?

Comment: @lentils `<2` means read from a file whose name is `2`.  `<&2` means read from the file whose file handle is number 2.  The use of higher numbers is an advanced topic but users can assign them for input or output for various purposes.  See [this exposition](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) for some examples.

Comment: `stty` gets the settings of the terminal opened on its stdin (you do `stty < /dev/other-tty` to get the settings of another terminal for instance). So it's not _strange_ that it won't work if its stdin is a pipe or that `<&2` works.

Comment: @Stephane - completely agreed. For clarity's sake - it's not strange because typical behavior for the tty is that file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 are links to the same file - your console, or /dev/tty. They're just different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: BEWARE that `cut -c` counts bytes so ANSI color escape sequences will soak up some space. I am currently in search of something that is escape sequence aware. You may build in a static offset if your colors are always consistent as a quick workaround and still use cut though.

Answer (score 11):

Some shells like `zsh`, `bash` or `mksh` automatically set the `$COLUMNS` variable to the width of the terminal, so you don't need to invoke `stty` here.

All the implementations of `ps` I tried that support that non-standard (BSD-type) syntax query the terminal width by themselves. I'm surprised yours doesn't. I expect it will look at the content of the `COLUMNS` *environment* variable though.

So you could do:

```
export COLUMNS; ps aux
```

If not,

```
ps aux | cut -c"1-$COLUMNS"
```

You can also tell your terminal not to wrap lines:

```
tput rmam
ps aux
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also handle `ps` output a little better.

```
ps --width ${n:-$COLUMNS} ${opts} #set ps terminal width

ps -ww ${opts} #no word wrap

ps -o ${only_interesting_output} ${opts} #trim output
```

That will tell `ps` to parse its output to your specifications as necessary.

Of course, if you don't word wrap, though, then you've got the problem of missing info. Do you really need all of it for all processes? Open it in a pager if so:

```
ps ww ${opts} | $PAGER
```

If not, specify what you do want to see:

```
ps -o args= -p $pid
```

Alternatively you can explicitly inform `ps` of your terminal `--width`:

```
man ps

...
```

> `w`   Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.
>
> `-w`  Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.
>
> `--width n`    Set screen width.

The `--width` thing works exactly to your requested specs without having to  involve any additional filters or ancillary processes *(which will likely only clutter your `-aux` output even more).* And with `$COLUMNS` as shown above and as Stephane points out it will even work dynamically.

It's probably worth noting, though, that I find people often try to add these kinds of unnecessary filters so they can accomodate a `|pipe` through *another* filter to parse output which is also pretty likely to be unnecessary. Of course, by *people* I mostly mean *me.*

The `-o`utput operand I mention above allows you to filter which columns `ps` displays, and when you add the `=`assigment you can even name the column as you please. I leave the assignment empty and hand it a target `-p`rocess `$pid` so the only output from `ps` at all is the `$pid` command name and its `args` at invocation. And `-o` barely scratches the surface of how you can define what `ps` will or won't display. This is the direction I would recommend you take, especially via:

```
man ps

...
```

> To see every process on the system using BSD syntax:
>
> > `ps ax`
> >
> > `ps axu`
>
> To print a process tree:
>
> > `ps -ejH`
> >
> > `ps axjf`
>
> To get info about threads:
>
> > `ps -eLf`
> >
> > `ps axms`
>
> To get security info:
>
> > `ps -eo euser,ruser,suser,fuser,f,comm,label`
> >
> > `ps axZ`
> >
> > `ps -eM`
>
> To see every process running as root (real & effective ID) in user format:
>
> > `ps -U root -u root u`
>
> To see every process with a user-defined format:
>
> > `ps -eo pid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat,wchan:14,comm`
> >
> > `ps axo stat,euid,ruid,tty,tpgid,sess,pgrp,ppid,pid,pcpu,comm`
> >
> > `ps -Ao pid,tt,user,fname,tmout,f,wchan`
>
> Print only the process IDs of syslogd:
>
> > `ps -C syslogd -o pid=`
>
> Print only the name of PID 42:
>
> > `ps -p 42 -o comm=`